# ANTLR4 - arguments in nested functions

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, ll-grammar

I have a problem with my antlr grammar or(lexer). In my case I need to parse a string with custom text and find functions in it. Format of function `$foo($bar(3),'strArg')`. I found solution in this post [ANTLR Nested Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955458/antlr-nested-functions?answertab=votes#tab-top) and little bit improved it for my needs. But while testing different cases I found one that brakes parser: `$foo($3,'strArg')`. This will throw IncorectSyntax exception. I tried many variants(for example not to skip `$` and include it in parsing tree) but it all these attempts were unsuccessfully

Lexer

```
lexer grammar TLexer;

TEXT
 : ~[$]
 ;

FUNCTION_START
 : '$' -> pushMode(IN_FUNCTION), skip
 ;

mode IN_FUNCTION;
  FUNTION_NESTED : '$' -> pushMode(IN_FUNCTION), skip;
  ID             : [a-zA-Z_]+;
  PAR_OPEN       : '(';
  PAR_CLOSE      : ')' -> popMode;
  NUMBER         : [0-9]+;
  STRING         : '\'' ( ~'\'' | '\'\'' )* '\'';
  COMMA          : ',';
  SPACE          : [ \t\r\n]-> skip;
```

Parser

```
options {
  tokenVocab=TLexer;
}

parse
 : atom* EOF
 ;

atom
 : text
 | function
 ;

text
 : TEXT+
 ;

function
 : ID params
 ;

params
 : PAR_OPEN ( param ( COMMA param )* )? PAR_CLOSE
 ;

param
 : NUMBER
 | STRING
 | function
 ;
```

Comment: `3` is not a correct function name (which is defined as `ID`, i.e. `[a-zA-Z_]+`).

Comment: I'm sorry for disinformation. I mean that this is `$foo($3)` incorrect case, but parser doesn't fail at `$3` (for parser it will seems as `NUMBER` nonterminal),it will fail if you add some more text `$foo($3) and some more text`. As I undestand this happens because `$` skipped and you still in `IN_FUNCTION` mode

Answer (score 0):

The parser does not fail on `$foo($3,'strArg')`, because when it encounters the second `$` it is already in `IN_FUNCTION` mode and it is expecting a parameter. It skips the character and reads a `NUMBER`.

If you want it to fail you need to unskip the dollar signs in the Lexer:

```
FUNCTION_START : '$' -> pushMode(IN_FUNCTION);

mode IN_FUNCTION;
    FUNTION_START : '$' -> pushMode(IN_FUNCTION);
```

and modify the `function` rule:

```
function : FUNCTION_START ID params;
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! You help  me to find the solution. But it must be little bit modified for parser `function : (FUNCTION_START|FUNTION_NESTED) ID params;`; That works fine

Comment: Yes, in my answer I changed the name of `FUNCTION_NESTED` without mentioning it.